# Only display address formatting information if the user has entered an address

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot web project with a Thymeleaf UI. My list-users page combines all address fields as follows:

```
<td>
    <div class="container">
        <span th:text="${tempUser.addressLine1}"></span>,<br>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.addressLine2 eq null}">
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.addressLine2 ne null}">
            <span th:text="${tempUser.addressLine2}"></span>,<br>
        </th:block>
        <span th:text="${tempUser.town}"></span>,<br>
        County <span th:text="${tempUser.county}"></span>,<br>
        <span th:text="${tempUser.country}"></span>,<br>
        <span th:text="${tempUser.postcode}"></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

The problem is that if the user doesn't specify an address they appear as:

[image]

How do I change this so the address appears as completely blank if the user hasn't enteres anything?

Comment: Just set the [th:if](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-evaluation) condition for `div class="container"` and include [null literal](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#the-null-literal) check concatenated with `and`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @Slava Ivanov's suggestion to include `null literal` check concatenated with `and`. I wanted this check to be a little finer grained so placed it in each `th` instead. Here's my code:

```
<td>
    <div class="container">
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.addressLine1 eq null and tempUser.addressLine1 eq ''}">
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.addressLine1 ne null and tempUser.addressLine1 ne ''}">
            <span th:text="${tempUser.addressLine1}"></span>,<br>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.addressLine2 eq null and tempUser.addressLine2 eq ''}">
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.addressLine2 ne null and tempUser.addressLine2 ne ''}">
            <span th:text="${tempUser.addressLine2}"></span>,<br>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.town eq null and tempUser.town eq ''}">
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.town ne null and tempUser.town ne ''}">
            <span th:text="${tempUser.town}"></span>,<br>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.county eq null and tempUser.county eq ''}">
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.county ne null and tempUser.county ne ''}">
            County <span th:text="${tempUser.county}"></span>,<br>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.country eq null and tempUser.country eq ''}">
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.country ne null and tempUser.country ne ''}">
            <span th:text="${tempUser.country}"></span>,<br>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.postcode eq null and tempUser.postcode eq ''}">
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${tempUser.postcode ne null and tempUser.postcode ne ''}">
            <span th:text="${tempUser.postcode}"></span>
        </th:block>
    </div>
</td>
```